# Connections pool dry out with mongodb transactions & atlas serverless plan

Tags: mongodb, go, transactions, serverless, mongodb-atlas

I'm encountering an issue with my mongoDB Atlas Serverless project. The database is used by a go application that leverages the transaction framework.

When I start my application, everything works fine. After some requests are sent to the database, all the following requests hang and return the following message :

```
timed out while checking out a connection from connection pool: context deadline exceeded; maxPoolSize: 100, connections in use by cursors: 0, connections in use by transactions: 100, connections in use by other operations: 0
```

Indeed, here is the monitoring graph I get from the web interface, that represent the amount of connections that are open with the database :

[image: number of connections]

We can clearly see when the application stops and starts. When the line becomes horizontal, that means the connections pool is exhausted.

Okay, so this is pretty explicit. The transactions that my requests use are keeping the connections alive, preventing the new ones from opening.

I don't understand why this happens. Here is my transaction method from the application perspective :

```golang
func (m MongoDB) Transaction(callback func(ctx mongo.SessionContext) (any, error)) (any, error) {
    session, err := m.DB.Client().StartSession()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed creating session for transaction | %s", err.Error())
    }

    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer session.EndSession(ctx)
    res, err := session.WithTransaction(ctx, callback)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return res, nil
}
```

As you can see, the `session.EndSession()` should end the connection properly at the end of the function.

Note that this problem occurs on the serverless version of mongodb, but NOT on Atlas free tier. What am I missing ?

Comment: Check the [official example](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#example-Client.StartSession-WithTransaction). Set read preference, and don't use a context with timeout to end the session. (And when you do use a context like that, store and defer-call the cancel function, don't just omit it.)

Comment: that does not answer my question, i purposefully simplified the code for the example

Comment: _"`EndSession()` should end the connection properly"_ You pass a context to it which may time out. A cancelled context means the function it was passed to should abort what it's doing. If the context you pass to `EndSession()` times out before `EndSession()` is called (or completed), `EndSession()` may not do what you expect it to do. That's why I wrote not to use a context with timeout. Please try the things I suggested.

Comment: if i use a context without timeout the call just hangs indefinitely